# After a few dozen hours http is slowing down by 3/4 times on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have 2 pc one on Vista and one on Windows 7. After a few dozen hours http is slowing down by 3/4 times on Windows 7 even when using a localhost server. I have to reboot to have normal speed again. This has never happened with Vista.

Has anybody experienced that ?

Answer (score 1):

When you say HTTP, what browser are you using or is this just a general thing?

You say "even when using a localhost server", just to rule it out, I wrote a [blog post about (very) slow load times in firefox](http://blog.williamhilsum.com/2009/11/speed-up-aspnet-development-server-on.html). If using Firefox, type `about:config` in the address bar and look for `network.dns.disableIPv6` - set this to true and it should speed up.

If however you are saying it is slow no matter what program you use, the best advise I can give is to simply try updating your network card driver - Windows 7 (as good as it is) comes with a few bad default drivers (especially, but not solely for Realtek network cards).

Answer (score 0):

Do you run any security software? Try disabling it.

Also give disabling Windows auto-tuning feature.
http://www.petri.co.il/improve_windows_vista_network_performance.htm